# Lose headers when send to camel hazelcast seda endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

I use camel with hazelcast component and faced the problem with exchange headers, when exchange goes through hazelcast seda.

I need to poll files from directory and send exchanges to seda hazelcast queue (to processing exchanges in cluster).

There is a simple example of this situation.
There are two routes, which runs in other JVMs:

First for polling files:

```
from("file:someFromFolder")
        .to("hazelcast:seda:queue?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcast-instance");
```

And second to processed this:

```
from("hazelcast:seda:queue?hazelcastInstance=#hazelcast-instance")
        .to("file:someToFolder");
```

When I tried to read headers like `Exchange.FILE_NAME` or others, i realized they are empty.

Is it possible to save headers while transferring exchanges through hazelcast seda component?

---

EDIT

When I set `transferExchange=true` as an option on the producer route endpoint, I catch exception:

```
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException: Message body of type org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile is not supported by this marshaller. on the exchange: Exchange[ID-DF-240815-MS12-60568-1487853045890-0-12][file.txt]
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchangeHolder.marshal(DefaultExchangeHolder.java:99)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchangeHolder.marshal(DefaultExchangeHolder.java:83)
                at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.seda.HazelcastSedaProducer.checkAndStore(HazelcastSedaProducer.java:55)
                at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.seda.HazelcastSedaProducer.process(HazelcastSedaProducer.java:42)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
                at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
                at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:442)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:214)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:178)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So could it be marshaller try to serialize all file data?

Comment: Did you try setting them as exchange properties? Although I am not sure if this works across JVM.

Comment: Yes, the result is same. Properties lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `transferExchange=true` as an option on the endpoint. By default its only the message body that is transferred. You can find this information in the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/hazelcast-component.html#HazelcastComponent-seda

Comment: Thanks, Claus. Yes, i have found this option, but i have maybe silly question about it. When I try to set this option, I have marshaller exception (see above). Hope, this option doesn't force camel transfer all file data to cluster queue?

Comment: Convert the message to a String or byte[] first, before sending to hazelcast

Comment: It works, but when I convert message body to String or byte[] it means I load all file content to memory. Is it possible to send a file reference to hazelcast instead sending all file content?

Comment: Then convert the body to the name of the file instead (eg your file reference)